# Overwrite a function of a stub

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, sinon

I want to test my google maps geocoder directive. There, I have a geocode constructor which I already stubbed:

```
...
link: function(scope) {
    var map,
        geocoder,
        myLatLng,
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 1,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    geocoder.geocode({'address': 'New York'}, function(results, status) {
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    }});
}
```

My stubbing code:

```
MapsGeocoderStub = sinon.stub();
$window.google = {
    maps: {
        Geocoder: MapsGeocoderStub
    }
};
```

I want to test `geocode.geocoder()` if it has been called. Therefore, I think I need to tell the stub that it has this method which is normally created by the constructor `google.maps.Geocoder()`.

Is stubbing the right way to do this anyway?

Comment: Can you show more code in your first code block?

Comment: I'm afraid that your code is not testable. In order to test the code with dependencies (`geocoder` in your case), the dependencies must be injected into the function instead of using `new` like this

Comment: To make your code testable, all dependencies like `geocoder` and `map` should be created as services and injected into the directive. When you do unit-testing, you could easily mock these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have in your test:

```
var geocodeInstance = {
    geocode: sinon.spy()
};

$window.google = {
    maps: {
        Geocoder: sinon.stub().returns(geocodeInstance);
    }
};
```

So here you said that your new $window.google.maps.Geocoder() returns geocodeInstance which has a method geocode. Also i used sinon.spy() because you just wanted to test that it was called. It can be a stub as well.

And later on:

```
expect(geocodeInstance.geocode).calledOnce;
```

I used expect since it's the way I am used to write my tests. 
Also try changing in your directive and inject $window and do:

```
geocoder = new $window.google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Comment: I had a mistake. I edited my answer and the test passes.